# 2 independent poisson processes: expected time of arrival of one process after the first arrival of the other has occurred

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

Drug incidents occur in a bathroom as a Poisson process at the rate of $2$/hour and Harry goes in to detect them as a Poisson process at the rate of $1$/hour. Assume that

- the 2 processes are independent
- if a drug incident has occured before, Harry can detect it whenever he goes in

**What is the expected time until Harry detects an incident of drug use?**

My take from this question is that I need to find
$$E(Y_n|Y_{n-1}<X_1\le Y_n)=\sum_yyP(Y_n-1<X_1,X_1\le y)\frac{P(Y_n=y)}{P(Y_{n-1}<X_1\le Y_n)}$$
Can't figure how to solve this, hints would be great.

Comment: Note that I don't want the expected number of times before it happens (as I found a similar question), I need the expected time when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_1$ be the first time when the drug incident happened and $T_1$ be the first time after $D_1$ when Harry goes in to detect them. Clearly, $\mathbb{E}(D_1)=\frac{1}{2}$ (this is the expected time for the first drug incident to happen). Now conditional on $D_1$, the first arrival of Harry will happen after an exponential wait time with mean $1$ (since the processes are independent). Hence the expected amount of time for this to happen is $1$. Therefore expected amount of time before Harry detects a drug incident is after $3/2$ hours.